# Site naively takes IP as a form argument - am I untrackable?

Tags: python, forms, python-3.x, post, ip

Note 1: I have no experience in web programming. 
Note 2: I don't do any harm. The comments get deleted automatically, and I don't plan to make a workaround though I think I could. I'm just playing.

This is the comment form of some website:

```
<form method="post" target="_top" action="index.php" name="akocommentform" />
<input type="hidden" value="com_akocomment" name="option"></input>
<input type="hidden" value="106" name="acitemid"></input>
<input type="hidden" value="20805" name="contentid"></input>
<input type="hidden" value="XX.XX.XXX.XXX" name="ip"></input> # My IP, as a form arg
<input type="hidden" value="entry" name="func"></input>
... stuff ...
<input class="inputbox" type="text" style="width: 250px;" title="Vardas" alt="Vardas" value="" name="acname"></input>
<input type="hidden" value="0" name="iduser"></input>
... more stuff ...
<textarea class="inputbox" wrap="virtual" title="Komentaras" name="comment" rows="8" style="width: 250px; height: 120px;"></textarea>
```

To spam 20 comments, I run this:

```
import requests
from random import choice, randrange as rr
from string import ascii_letters as letters

def fake_ip():
    return str(rr(256))+'.'+str(rr(256))+'.'+str(rr(256))+'.'+str(rr(256))

comment = ''.join([choice(letters) for x in range(1000)])
name = ''.join([choice(letters) for x in range(15)])
payload = {
    'option' : 'com_akocomment',
    'acitemid' : '106',
    'contentid' : '20586',
    'ip' : fake_ip(), # IT WORKS!
    'func' : 'entry',
    'iduser' : '0',
    'acname' : name,
    'comment' : comment }

for i in range(20):
    response = requests.post('http://www.nyksciai.lt', data=payload)
    print (response.status_code, response.reason)
```

Now I've got two questions:

- If this is the only code site uses to receive comments, how can it possibly track me with wrong IP in its database?

Comment: Neither of your questions are on-topic. We don't know who that person is, so we don't know if they "forgot" or if they're completely ignorant of security 101. Whether it's legal or not depends on a bunch of stuff. We're not lawyers. (BTW: you're not untrackable at all. If you believe that, you need to take web sec 101 too :-) )

Comment: 'is it legal' deleted

Comment: changing second question

Comment: @Mat Done. Is this question alright now?

Comment: Clearly the site already knows your IP address, because it was able to provide it in the html

Comment: Still speculation. For all we know, they might have called the FBI already because they track mismatches between form sub IP addresses and actual TCP endpoint connection addresses. And they're mad you posted comments.

Comment: @Eric So why pass it into form if you already know it?

Comment: Convenience? Honestly, who knows? We're not the author of the form.

Comment: @b4hand Okay, I get it now. So the site KNOWS my real IP and PROBABLY tracks it too, and records my comment IP for (probably) convenience, such as quick comment IP look up or something else. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, the web server will include the source IP in the web server request log. This will use the connecting IP directly. So if you are receiving the form response with your real IP then it is probably being logged and thus you *can* be tracked.

Also testing the security of someone else's web site without permission can be considered harm in and of itself. Definitely spamming someone's web site with comments could be considered harmful as it is a form of denial of service attack. This is true even if the comments are automatically removed.

What you are doing is not "play" and could get you into a lot of trouble. If you want to experiment, you should learn how to setup the experiment on your own computer.

Comment: Okay, I won't do it anymore. Sorry.